# Should a feature importance score be invariant to transformations of the response?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, feature-selection, philosophical

This is more of a philosophical question that came up in a discussion with a friend - consider some 'feature importance' procedure associated to a model (say a regression model). You run your model and then compute feature importance scores for each of your $p$ covariates, and you get $p$ numbers in $[0,1]$ say.

Then, you transform your response $g(Y)$ and repeat the process, computing feature importance scores again.

Question: Is it desirable (of a feature importance procedure) that the two sets of scores are the same ? That is, should a feature importance procedure ideally be invariant to transformations of the response? Or should a feature importance procedure merely give you a score for each covariate relative to all other covariates in the model, and so should just maintain the relative ranks of the feature importances.

Comment: Transformations of the response affect the evaluated loss function. Basically, you are saying that the loss function is not important when, in fact, there is the whole body of literature confirming that for some problems one loss function performs better than another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a very hard ask for general $g$.  If you restricted to, say, nonconstant linear $g$, and you want normalized importances, then it seems reasonable.

For a really pathological example, let $y=x_1+1000x_2$, with $x_i\in\{0,1\}$. Clearly $x_2$ is significantly more important.  But let $g=\operatorname{parity}: \mathbb{Z}\to\{0,1\}$, and now $g(y)=g(x_1)$, and $x_2$ is irrelevant to any new model.

For something more continuous, consider instead $y=(2+0.1x_1+0.1x_2)^{x_3}$ with $x_1, x_2$ small scale and $x_3$ discrete in $\{1, 2\}$, and $g(y)=y^3$.  Then $x_3$ "ought" to be the most important for both models, but its importance "ought" to be even greater in the transformed model, I think.

For nonconstant linear $g$, consider the basic case of a linear regression.  Scaling $y$ will just scale the coefficients by the same amount, and a shift will get absorbed by the intercept term.  Normalizing coefficients to get "importances" (multiplying by the standard deviation of the $x$ which hasn't changed, and dividing by the standard deviation of $y$, which has also scaled) washes out the change.